# Differences between combinations and permutations.

Tags: probability

My problems are with the following question:

> Four digits are selected independently at random (without repetition) from $\{0,1,...,9\}$. What is the probability that the four digits form a run? e.g $ (2,3,4,5)$

The probability of any selection is ${10 \choose 4}$ because we are not repeating digits. We can enumerate all the possible runs: $$\{0,1,2,3\},\{1,2,3,4\},...,\{6,7,8,9\}. $$ There are seven in total so the answer is $$7/{10 \choose 4}.$$

My query is as follows, the selection $\{1,2,3,4\} = \{2,1,3,4\}$, as we are dealing with combinations. But the r.h.s does not form a run. Does the question mean that it is possible that we can rearrange the 4 numbers into a run?

Or is it that by using combinations we enforce an ordering?

The answer agrees with what is said in the book. Should The answer be given in permutations instead?

Comment: By using *permutations*, we enforce an ordering. For example, if there are 3 runners in a race, A can go in 3 places, B can go in 2 places, and C can go in the last race.

Comment: The question is inherently ambiguous about whether they must form a run *in the order chosen* or whether they must form a run *after you rearrange them in increasing order*.  A better question writer would have written a clearer question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is positive, but not the second one. More specifically:

- Suppose the ordering does not matter. Then, the set of favorable outcomes will consist of 7 subsets as you correctly point out. The set of all outcomes will be comprised of C(10,4) subsets. So, the answer turns out to be 7/C(10,4).
- Now, suppose the ordering indeed matters. This time, the set of favorable outcomes will contain 7 permutations. On the other hand, the set of all outcomes will include C(10,4)*4!= P(10,4) permutations. Thus, the answer would be different: 7/P(10,4), or more equivalently, 7/C(10,4)*4!.

Hope this helps. Have a good day.

Comment: This can't be right.  If order doesn't matter, there are many more possibilities.  In both cases, though, we're counting permutations, not combinations.

Comment: @RobertShore what do you mean? Please be more specific. Note that C(n,r)*r!=P(n,r).

Comment: If the order matters (and the run has to be ascending), then there are only $7$ possibilities because the run is completely characterized by its starting number and there are only $7$ permissible starting numbers.  If the order doesn't matter so that any combination that uses four consecutive numbers works, then there are $7 \cdot 24=168$ possible permutations that work.  Either way, the universe of possible permutations has size $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 = 5040$.

Comment: @RobertShore You are right. Thanks for alerting me to that. I have revised my solution, which should be ok now.

Comment: If you choose digits randomly, you need to use permutations and not combinations because you have to include all possible cases.

Comment: Your answer is now exactly backwards.  If order matters, there are $7$ solutions.

Comment: So am I correct in saying that $\{1,2,3,4\} = \{2,1,3,4\}$ in the case of combinations. We adjust for this in the calculation of the binomial coefficient. That is, in the $4!$ in the denominator of $\frac{n!}{(n-4)!4!}$?

Comment: @HMPtwo  Yes. In the case of combinations, one can rearrange the four numbers into a run, as it renders the ordering immaterial. As long as the order is of no importance, one must have recourse to combinations, in which case counting involves the counting of subsets, not permutations. The moment the order becomes important, counting refers to keeping a tally of the permutations, which means that each subset must be counted 4! times for the question under consideration. Once more, bear in mind that P(n,r)=C(n,r)*r!.